# Converting the integral for the area of a circle from an expression involving $dp$ to one involving $dr$

Tags: calculus, integration

From the Better Explained website, the integral for calculating the area of a circle with respect to its perimeter is given as $$\int_0^{2\pi r} \frac 12 r dp$$ where $r$ is the radius and $p$ is the perimeter. To play around with my understanding of transforming the expression, I tried to find a value of $dp$ and substitute it.

Given that the perimeter of a circle is $P = 2 \pi r$, I reasoned that  $\frac{dp}{dr} = 2 \pi$ and consequently that $dp = 2\pi dr$. I substituted the value for $dp$ into the original equation and got $$\int_0^{2\pi r} \frac 12 r 2 \pi dr$$ Wolfram Alpha evaluates this integral to be $2 \pi ^3 r^2$, which is not right at all. I must have made a logical error somewhere, but I have no idea where.

Background: I did basic integration about 8 years ago in highschool, and am now doing a course where this is assumed knowledge, so I have been trying to teach myself the assumed knowledge while keeping up with the usual content. I'm aware that $dy$ and other such terms can't be thrown around like they are variables, but through some theorems they can act like regular variables in some situations. I feel like this is an area where my understanding is lacking, and if I had to guess where my error was, I would say that I probably did something invalid with a $d$ somewhere.

Comment: You are using $r$ sometimes as a constant (radius) and sometimes as variable (parameter parametrizing the perimeter). That's the problem.

Comment: Why not simply $\int_0^{2\pi r}\frac{1}{2}rdp=\frac{r}{2}\int_0^{2\pi r}dp=\frac{r}{2}\times 2\pi r=\pi r^2$?

Comment: Would you be able to explain what you mean? I thought that perimeter/area/radius were all varying.

Answer (score 1):

What you have can be explained by figure 1.
If you consider a very small sector which has arc length **dp** and a radius of **R** then the area **dA** of the sector will approximately be **1/2*R*dp** and if all the **dp**s are of unit length then you'll add them **2πR** times. Now, this is a sum of continuous variables which can be written as an Integral.

$$dA = \frac 12*R*dp$$
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi R}dA$$
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi R} \frac 12 R dp$$
$$A = \pi R^2$$

Now, if you want the same integral in form of radius, think of small ring or a circular strip with perimeter of **p=2πr**, radius **r** and thickness of **dr**. (look at figure 2) If you add area of all the small rings you should get total area of the circle. Area of a small ring dA will be **2*π*r*dr**. Since the radius is continuously varying the sum can be expressed in form of following integral, and if all the **dr**s of unit length you will add it **R** times.

$$dA = 2*\pi *r*dr$$
$$A = \int_0^{R}dA$$
$$A = \int_0^{R} 2\pi rdr$$
$$A = \pi R^2$$

all the approximations work because the fractions like **dr**, **dp** are very very small. i.e. are of the sector = 1/2*R*d because shape of the sector is equivalent to a triangle.

Now, as far as I understand you can't inter-substitute in this case because in substitution you change a integral from one variable to another if you have a relation between them. Here dp is related to R and not r so you cant apply substitution rule, rather they are simplification of more general integral $$A = \int_0^{R} \int_0^{2\pi R} \frac rR dp*dr$$.

If you want I can explain this term to you. Both of the individual cases can be achieved after integrating with respect to any one of them.

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral

[Figures 1 & 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtJz0.jpg)